# ¿Cuál es el mejor término para traducir la palabra "nice" en un contexto de Matemáticas?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, matemáticas

¡Hola!
Estos días comencé a trabajar con mi tesina y me encontré con un término para el cual no acabo de encontrar una buena traducción al español sin que se pierda la seriedad del trabajo o que quede muy fuera de lugar. El término aparece en la siguiente oración

> A maximal locally finite cellular family of open sets is called **nice**.

Dicha oración viene en la siguiente imagen que a su vez es un extracto del artículo que se puede encontrar [aquí](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119676/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_48-2007-3_11.pdf)
[image]

En pocos términos, dice que cuando una familia de de abiertos es maximal, localmente finita y celular es llamada *nice*. Hasta ahora, en la redacción de mi trabajo me he referido a estas familias como *familias nice* pero obviamente queda muy fuera de lugar. Intenté con *familia óptima*, *buena familia*, pero siento que es mala la traducción porque a veces se usan precisamente las palabras óptima y buena como adjetivos en este contexto y solo causaría confusión. ¿Hay algún término que sea mejor que pudieran sugerirme?

Gracias por leerme.

Comment: Me suena como a una familia bien portada, una familia con modales o educación, una familia ejemplar, ordenada o normal. Por allí anda la idea, pero no se me ocurre un buen término.

Comment: Me habría encantado el término de familia ordenada o familia normal pero esos ya hacen referencia a otros conceptos totalmente distintos en el contexto en el que estoy trabajando. Esperemos a ver si alguien tiene otra idea.

Comment: "nice" tiene la acepción de "fitting", que se podría traducir como adecuada, apropiada, apta, calificada, cómoda, idónea, indicada, oportuna, procedente, propicia, propia, congurente, ideal, aparejada, etc. También da la idea de correcta, puntillosa, o cabal. Me inclino por "apta, idónea, o cabal". Una familia cabal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En [esta tesis doctoral](https://digibug.ugr.es/bitstream/handle/10481/47257/2656225x.pdf) en español la autora usa el término *nice* 312 veces sin despeinarse.

Inventarte un término que no sea del agrado de algún miembro del tribunal puede ser desastroso. Ya llegará el momento en el que puedas sentar cátedra. Si ni tú ni tu director de tesina habéis visto una traducción ya establecida, yo preguntaría a otros profesores e indagaría por foros de matemáticas. Y si no encuentras ninguna publicación en la que te puedas apoyar, mejor lo dejas sin traducir.

Eso sí, yo lo escribiría en cursiva todas las veces.